# Is there any way to disable touch for tabs in ActionBar in Xamarin.Android?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I need to disable the touch for any of the tabs or all the tabs in the ActionBar. Please refer the below image,

[image]

If I touch the second tab(Page2), the corresponding page should not navigate. i.e., the second tab should be in disabled state.

Is there any way to achieve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your question is not so clear to be very honest but i guess on page two click you want to disable lower tabs right?

Comment: basically he wants to disable changing current page inside TabbedPage

Comment: Yes, what @NickKovalsky said is my actual requirement.